# Android camera application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera

I m **new** in android.. and I want to create a camera android application..

These are the following codes...
It works fine when i m starting my app in my phone [ galaxy note n7000] but after capturing an image a problem appears.. when i click save button an error dialouge appeares and my app stopped..I think there is some problem in **onActivityResult()** method .. please help..

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Take photo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cameratest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }  });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bm= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cameratest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cameratest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should post the relevant logs as well.

Comment: whenever you post something when application crash,you should post log cat as well,as it's easy to detect an error.please post your full log cat data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Start Camera like this, use this code in onCreate method.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "";

        filePath = filePath + File.separator + "temp_img.jpg";
        File f = new File(filePath);
        try {
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri currImageURI = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            currImageURI = data.getData();
        }
        if (currImageURI == null) {
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "";
            filePath = filePath + File.separator + "temp_img.jpg";
            File f = new File(filePath);

            currImageURI = Uri.fromFile(f);
        }

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,
                    currImageURI);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And Make sure to initialize iv in onCreate.

```
iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

In Last add permission to write file on sdcard.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Hey..Thanks for reply.. 
Yah error does not appear now its good.but image is not set in imageview.. I initialize **iv** into my **oncreate** method.. though no image does not appear

Comment: @Brett can u please vote up and accept this as answer, I am happy to help you.

Comment: Hey @sandy could you help me on the following topic..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066941/android-connection-with-mysql-using-json

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Welcome to Android I also have done this assignment when i have started.
>   here is the code for camera.java

`package com.example.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bm;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
            R.drawable.splash_background);
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

public void initialize() {
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        try {
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .setBitmap(bm);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bm = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

}

Here is xml for activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSetWall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Wall" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivReturnedPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibTakePic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_background" />
```

check this link[Video tutorial for android](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Android%20Application%20Development%20Tutorial%20-%2038%20-%20XML%20Image%20View%20for%20Camera%20Application)

Answer (score 0):

exact source of error could be found once you show your logcat output but it seems like the problem is that you haven't initialized ImageView iv anywhere but your are setting bitmap for it in the onActivityResult method. First initialize the imageView somewher; may be in the onCreate method. e.g do this in your onCreate method :

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.some_id);
```