# Android connection with mysql using json

Tags: java, android

JSON-MYSQL connectivity with 2 text fields [name and comments] in a mysql table named 'emp' in my server .. and it woks fine ..but now I want to store image , with an extra field... but don't know how..pls help..
These is my follwing code..

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jparser;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddnewActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name;
    EditText comments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnew);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
            name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
            String nm=name.getText().toString();
            comments=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
            String com=comments.getText().toString();

            if("".equals(nm) || "".equals(com)){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty field detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
            else{

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("name", nm);
                    json.put("comments", com);


                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String url = "http://share88.hostzi.com/parser/json_req.php";

                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
                    request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    if (entity != null) {
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }
                name.setText(null);
                comments.setText(null);    


                } catch (Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Request failed: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }


            }

            }catch(Exception e){}   

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addnew, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_addnew.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AddnewActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/addnewcontent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/addcomments" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/addname" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AddnewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jparser;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddnewActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name;
    EditText comments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnew);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        Button save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
            name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
            String nm=name.getText().toString();
            comments=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
            String com=comments.getText().toString();

            if("".equals(nm) || "".equals(com)){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty field detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
            else{

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("name", nm);
                    json.put("comments", com);


                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String url = "http://share88.hostzi.com/parser/json_req.php";

                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
                    request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    if (entity != null) {
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }
                name.setText(null);
                comments.setText(null);    


                } catch (Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Request failed: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }


            }

            }catch(Exception e){}   

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addnew, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

And my PHP files are

**json_res.php**

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$result=mysql_query("SELECT* FROM emp");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();

?>
```

and **json_req.php**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

include "connect.php";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('','".$obj->{'name'}."', '".$obj->{'comments'}."')");
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Do you want to send image from android and store it in mysql database?

Comment: @Vino.. yes I want to choose image from android then send it via json and store it into mysql database..I know this is the process but dont know how to implement into my above code..

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps to send image from Android to Server**

If you want to send image via JSON then you need to convert it to string because JSON doesn't transfer Image directly

**Android**

**STEP 1** : Convert your image in to String using `Base64`[ Which encodes the image to a string]

**STEP 2** : Pass the converted string in JSON.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
json.put("name", nm);
json.put("comments", com);
json.put("image",convertedString);
```

**In Server Side**

**STEP 1** Receive the JSON String.($yourimageString)

**STEP 2** Decode the JSON string to image using  `base64_decode ($yourimageString)` method.

**STEP 3** Now write this in to file. You will get your image now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanx for your answer... But i m confused how to create an image picker in my form -> activity_addnew.xml .. please help

Comment: Hi Brett, u can choose image by launching gallery like                             Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),100);

Comment: hey imager picker is working fine thank you..
every thing is fine no error but my database not updating with image string..
here is my code..

iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

and i send img_str like  json.put("img", img_str);

and i also edit my php file in server with 

$obj = json_decode($json);

Comment: you mean string not updating in server side?

Comment: yes my server side code is ..

<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

include "connect.php";



mysql_query("INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('','".$obj->{'name'}."', '".$obj->{'comments'}."', '".$obj->{'img'}."')");
mysql_close($con);


?> ... My database still not updating.. I use img column as a long text